# In MATLAB, Saving Plots to a Folder with Title Name

Tags: matlab, plot, output

In MATLAB, I'm trying to plot a series of plots in a loop with the following data:

```
    x1 = [ 1 2 3 4 5]
    y1 = [ 1 1 1 1 1]
    x2 = [ 1 2 3 4 5]
    y2 = [ 2 2 2 2 2]
    x3 = [ 1 2 3 4 5]
    y3 = [ 2 2 2 2 2]

    plot(x,y)
    title('First Plot')
```

THEN suppress the output and save all plots to a folder,

with the each file displaying the title names:

```
  First Plot
  Second Plot
  Third Plot
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Saving the plot to a file, with the title name, you can use the following

```
    graphTitle='first plot';
    hold on
    h=figure(1);
    title('first plot');
    hold off
    fileName=strcat('path to save',graphTitle,'.jpg');
    print(h,'-djpeg',fileName);
```

If you need to create and save a lot of files, create a vector of file names, of the same size as the number of vectors (or dimension of the matrix) you need to plot. In a look create a handle using the index of the current file Name and do the above, you should be able to print the with the title you need etc.

When you use the above code, all the plots are visible on the screen and then printed to the file.

Comment: `strcat` can be replaced with brackets: `['path to save', graphTitle, 'j.jpg')]`. Also, I don't see the need for `hold on` and `hold off` here.